# How to make a history for my web browser with JavaFX?

Tags: text, field, browser-history

i'm building a web browser with javafx and currently i'm making the history. So i have a `TextField fxid: "urltext"` this field get the URL of the opening page and it changes while entering in another web page. Also i have many text fields in the history part: `TextField1 fxid: t1` and `TextField2 fxid: t2` and `TextField3 fxid: t3` and many others. I want : if the TextField `urltext` contains an other URL (means the URL has changed after entering in other page) so the `urltext` contains a new URL and if the URL changes in every moment should set the new URL in a new textField in the history part. for example: `urltext` contains "www.google.com" and then the user enter to another page like "stackoverflow.com" so `t1` should set this new URL on it and then the url has changed should be stted on `t2` like that. Can anybody give me some code to explain me how ? and thank you

Comment: [WebHistory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebHistory.html) is already provided by the [WebEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) for the [WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) via [`webview.getWebEngine().getHistory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#getHistory--).

Comment: If you have specific questions with how to integrate the history into your application you should provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e., minimal executable code which replicates the issue, and not ask "give me some code".